# I want to use specific css code (that over rides master css) on buttons

Tags: css

I am working on a website and I am adding a few buttons, problem is it takes the master css and ruins the look of my buttons.

the code in the page (for the buttons) is :

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="../frequently-asked-questions#tab1">Placing an Order</a></li>
  <li><a href="../frequently-asked-questions#tab2">Delivery</a></li>
  <li><a href="../frequently-asked-questions#tab3">Returns</a></li>
  <li><a href="../frequently-asked-questions#tab4">VAT</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
  * {padding:0; margin:0;}
  html {
     padding:15px 15px 0;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     font-size:14px;
   }

  p, h3 { 
    margin-bottom:15px;
  }

  div {
    padding:10px;
    width:600px;
    background:#fff;
  }

  .tabs li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
  }

  .tabs a {
    padding:5px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#104e8b;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  .tabs a.active {
    background:#00b0d8;
    color:#ffff;
  }
```

I don't know if you can see that code but it is only list items in a < ul class = "tabs"> div. excuse the spaces but it wouldn't appear.

MY QUESTION is : how to I get the .css code to work on a specific part of a page ?  My page takes the .css from the rest of the .css file and it messes everything up.  Can I designate the < ul > a name and refer to it in .css ? It hasn't worked for me.

Please help ! Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, It's unclear totally that what exactly you're asking.....

Comment: If i am not wrong you want to have a custom style for a list.

Comment: you want to have 1 html 2++ css files? and define region where each css file works on that 1 html?

Comment: Sounds like you have other css styling which is *overriding* your button styles. To fix this - make your button styles more specific

Comment: use `!important` in your CSS to override master styles!

Comment: I want to use above css in 1 page.  But it doesn't display right because it uses other css.  Can I use the above css in a single page ?

Comment: HEY PBALDAUL '!IMPORTANT' WORKED !! I added it to the CSS and it was then used for my buttons.  I hope it doesn't mess somewhere else up on the site but thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to avoid !important when possible though.

It sounds like your problem, which isn't explained very clearly, by using more specific selectors. The idea in css is to define general style that apply to everything, and selector specificity rules allow you to apply exceptions to styles specific components.

For example, define .tabs {style A} for the whole site, but for one specific page, define #specific-page .tabs {style B}. Style B will only be used under the #specific-page element

This article explains this important css concept very well: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

EDIT: I suggest reading about contextual styling because what I advise here is not ideal

Comment: sorry if i was not very clear.  '!IMPORTANT' WORKED !! I added it to the CSS and then the css was used for my buttons. I don't yet if it will effect the rest of the site

Comment: It was clear, I just wanted to add what I think is a better solution